# Why does Earth have only one moon?

Tags: the-moon, earth

The moon was first formed billions of years ago when a Mars-sized object crashed into Earth. The pieces formed over time to create our moon. Why was only one moon formed? Could Earth have had other moons that no longer exist?

Comment: BTW, welcome to our site! I think you've asked a good question (+1!) about why the debris from the hypothesised impact of Theia didn't coalesce into two smaller moons, but when I looked at the answer to the linked question, I realised it explains why. If your post does get closed as a duplicate of that earlier question, don't be discouraged: if you get another upvote and (maybe) another comment, your question stays in our library and can provide a signpost for others who might have a similar query but would otherwise not have found their way to the main question and its answer. :-)

Comment: I similarly upvoted and voted to close. This is a good question, but a nice answer already exists.